# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bidParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\pdologin\index.php on line 14

Tags: php

When i run the code this error will come: -

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bidParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\pdologin\index.php on line 14

Please solve my problem. I am new in PDO php. Please help me to solve my error.

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['signup']))
    {
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $mob=$_POST['mob'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname,email,pass,mob,address) VALUES(:fname,:email,:pass,:mob,:address)";
     $query = $conn->prepare($sql);   
    $query->bindParam(':fname',$fname);
        $query->bidParam(':email',$email);
        $query->bindParam(':pass',$pass);
        $query->bindParam(':mob',$mob);
        $query->bindParam(':address',$address);
        $query->execute();
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter full name"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email"/>
            <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="enter password"/>
            <input type="text" name="mob" placeholder="enter mobile number"/>
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="enter address"/>

            <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Signup" />
            </form>



        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `:bidParam()` :thinking: maybe you meant bi***n***dParam()

Comment: This is a typo issue and this topic should be closed. OP you should actually look at error message next time.

Comment: Thank you so much. you solve my problem. I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misstype.

Change 
`$query->bidParam(':email',$email);`
to
`$query->bindParam(':email',$email);`

You should actually look at error message next time.

Comment: Select my answer as a solution please =)